# Member Function Pointer in Qt C++

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qt4

```
typedef void (classname::*funptr)(int);

void classname::func(int p)
{
...
}

void classname::someotherfunc()
{
........

 funptr ptr;
 ptr= &(classname::func);                 // this is error line 

...........
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression.
```

Next I tried

```
ptr= classname::func;
```

which gives this error:

```
error C3867: 'FaceBinUI::progress_update': function call missing argument list; use '&FaceBinUI::progress_update' to create a pointer to member
```

Please suggest some solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is telling you exactly what you need to do:

```
ptr= &classname::func;
```

So just lose the parentheses.